# Prediction in Poisson regression, data frame in R (Error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1)

Tags: r, regression, prediction, poisson

After building the Poisson regression model we can build a prediction using predict function in R. But, I have some problem where I cannot working out with my newdata set in R. It gives an error.

```
newdata <- data.frame(
    patient = mean(myd$patient),
    hypertensive = factor(1:4, levels = 1:4, labels = levels(myd$hypertensive)),
    PCOS = factor(1:2, levels = 1:2, labels = levels(myd$PCOS)),
    age = factor(1:3, levels = 1:3, labels = levels(myd$age)),
    miscarriage = factor(1:2, levels=1:2, labels = levels(myd$miscarriage)))
```

> Error in data.frame(patient = mean(myd$patient), hypertensive = factor(1:4,  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 4, 2, 3

Comment: Why the "convoluted" `factor` declarations? Why don't you just do e.g. `hypertensive = as.factor(myd$hypertensive)` and so on?

Comment: Also, your question plus title has nothing to do with Poisson regression.

Comment: try `expand.grid` instead of `data.frame`, that is probably what you want instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `expand.grid` as @Neal Fultz writes. You variable have length 2-4 in the argument to `data.frame` which requires that they all have equal length.

## Update

I do not know why someone downvoted my answer but I expand my answer here to make it crystal clear. The issue is that the input arguments to `data.frame` have different lengths

```r
> # create data example
> myd <- data.frame(
+   # NOTICE: I assume that your patient covariate is continuous -- otherwise I 
+   #         do not get why you would take a mean
+   patient      = 1:12,
+   # here are the factors
+   hypertensive = rep(letters[1:4], 3),
+   PCOS         = rep(letters[1:2], 6),
+   age          = rep(letters[1:3], 4),
+   miscarriage  = rep(letters[1:2], 6)
+ )
> myd # show data
   patient hypertensive PCOS age miscarriage
1        1            a    a   a           a
2        2            b    b   b           b
3        3            c    a   c           a
4        4            d    b   a           b
5        5            a    a   b           a
6        6            b    b   c           b
7        7            c    a   a           a
8        8            d    b   b           b
9        9            a    a   c           a
10      10            b    b   a           b
11      11            c    a   b           a
12      12            d    b   c           b
> 
> # your issue is that the length you pass to data.frame differs
> length(factor(1:4, levels = 1:4, labels = levels(myd$hypertensive)))
[1] 4
> length(factor(1:2, levels = 1:2, labels = levels(myd$PCOS)))
[1] 2
> 
> # however, you can use expand.grid
> newdata  <- expand.grid(
+   patient = mean(myd$patient),
+   hypertensive = factor(1:4, levels = 1:4, labels = levels(myd$hypertensive)),
+   PCOS = factor(1:2, levels = 1:2, labels = levels(myd$PCOS)),
+   age = factor(1:3, levels = 1:3, labels = levels(myd$age)),
+   miscarriage = factor(1:2, levels=1:2, labels = levels(myd$miscarriage))) 
> 
> # it will have many examplse though 
> nrow(newdata)
[1] 48
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response. your explanation very clear to me.

Comment: Happy to help. Please close the question if it answered you question by clicking the accept button.